# Criar um arrastar para vários objetos SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Estou utilizando o Vue.js para criar um clone do jflap. Porém estou tendo problemas para criar o arrastar para cada objeto. No caso, o círculo ao se clicar e arrastar este, deve acompanhar a rota do mouse até o soltar do botão onde deve permanecer neste último ponto.

o `$data` dos objetos está da seguinte forma:

```
nodes: [
  {
    cx: 100,
    cy: 100,
    id: 0,
    selected: false,
    ini: false,
    final: false
  }
],
```

O SVG para criar os nós:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300" version="1.1" v-on="click: add">
  <g>
    <circle
      v-on="click: selectFunc"
      v-repeat="nodes"
      id="{{id}}"
      cx="{{cx}}"
      cy="{{cy}}"
      r="30"
      v-class="selected: selected"
    >
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Existem alguns atributos a mais do Vue que estou usando para as demais funcionalidades, porém a base é esta, nada complicado. Consigo adicionar novos nós na posição que desejo e remover o nó que desejo, porém ainda preciso terminar a movimentação destes nós e por fim adicionar as ligações por linhas, mas esta é a última parte.

Como não encontrei nada na internet com relação a arrastar usando o Vue.js estou pedindo aqui, existem informações de um arrastar, mas aí é o usando do HTML 5.

jfiddler do que já fiz: https://jsfiddle.net/a4uwu3sa/

> Note porém que caso faça o teste pelo firefox ele não esta pegando a posição correta, apenas no chrome e derivados que aparece na posição correta, isto eu pretendo resolver depois. Minha prioridade é mover os objetos e depois adicionar as linhas de ligação.

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFIddle e juntar à pergunta?

Comment: Adicionei o código no jfiddler. Bom eu sei que eventos no vue.js utiliza-se o v-on, porem a documentação só tem o evento de click documentado, então não sei se existe outros eventos suportados para arrastar de mouse.

Comment: A solução para este problema é simples, na documentação não informa, porém é suportado `mouseover`, `mousedown`, `mousemove`. Agora preciso que o movimento seja realizado enquanto inicia o `mousedown`, passando para o `mousemove` e finalize com `mouseup`. Se alguém souber como fazer a serie entre dentro do Vue.js agradeço.

Comment: Adicionando a versão com movimento, porem o movimento e so ao passar o mouse em cima, ainda não consegui realizar por clique, arrasta e solta.
https://jsfiddle.net/a4uwu3sa/6/

Comment: Thiago, conseguiste resolver isto? vi de novo o jsFiddle agora e está com erros na consola...